# Why typescript does not infer type that promise resolves

Tags: typescript, type-inference

```
const destructPromise = <TResult>(promise: Promise<TResult>) => {
  return promise.then(data => [data, null]).catch(err => [null, err]);
};

const test = async () => Promise.resolve({ a: 1 });

const fun = async () => {
  const [a, b] = await destructPromise(test()); // Why in this example the types of variables 'a' and 'b' are inferred as any?
};
```

Why in this example the types of variables 'a' and 'b' are inferred as any?

Comment: Do you expect the type to resolve to TResult?

Comment: I expect that at least type of 'a' will be infered as TResult | null

Comment: @CaptainChaos two captains on the board :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the return value of the destructed promise has to account for the possible results of both the `.then` and `.catch` cases.

The `.then` is easy enough, this returns `Promise<(TResult | null)[]>`. However the `.catch` is the issue because by default, the type of an error parameter is `any`, giving us a return type of `any[]` for that branch.

To fix this, give your function an explicit return type that properly captures the distinction between your two cases:

```
const destructPromise = <TResult extends unknown>(promise: Promise<TResult>): Promise<[TResult, null] | [null, any]> => {
  return promise.then(data => [data, null] as [TResult, null]).catch(err => [null, err] as [null, any]);
};
```

Now, when you use that, your variables will be given the proper types!:

```
const test = async () => Promise.resolve({ a: 1 });

const fun = async () => {
  const [a, b] = await destructPromise(test());
  if (a) {
    const some_number = a.a
  }
};
```

Where in this example `a` will be given type `{a: number} | null`, and `b` is still typed as `any`.

If you still want to remove the `any`, you'll have to return a known type from the `.catch` block, perhaps by wrapping the `err` parameter using `new Error(err)`.

Answer (score 1):

Just an extension of @CRice answer.

You can infer all arguments with help of small function.

Consider this example:

```js
const tuple = <A, B>(a: A, b: B): [A, B] => [a, b]

const destructPromise = <TResult,>(promise: Promise<TResult>) => {
    return promise
        .then(data => tuple(data, null))
        .catch((err: unknown) => tuple(null, err));
};

const test = async () => Promise.resolve({ a: 1 });

const fun = async () => {
    const [a, b] = await destructPromise(test());
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBFCuAHANgUxgXhgHgIIBoYAhAPgAoBDALhgJgCMaiBKGgbTqIF1MSY2KhelwBQI0JFgATVNABO8YFAAKckAFsAlhHRZsAFQBKs%20Mij5yiNVp01VG7agPGIpqCWa8YAbxEx-MHKoCHJgMFYOOn4BMQB0UAAWqGBkUhRQFF4IKKip6YIwYKbIzMzRMf6xwOnACWRkqHJyNPBgANZgIADuYJ4YfNloZEXIyISNcqUA3CIAvjPi4NBwsrBYFBAAnmDAMGR9fPY2qLFBECDIAG653jDUMACMMLPMCxLLAGatmHdbO3sHHzlGDvWACIQ8dZdCiaaSrBRKI6OMhQVb7V5zKZAA)

You can also use `as const` instead of `tuple`.

I have used `unknown` for `catch(error)` because it is much safer.

As you might have noticed, `tuple` function does job for you. All arguments are infered.